# How can I achieve this ribbon effect with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this effect. I want the two bars on each side to extend to the edge of the page. This is the closest I've come. I obviously need to flip the "folds" somehow, and I need to get each light blue bar to extend to the edge of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/vPJ8g/

```
<div id="ribbon">
    <span id="content">Call us today! 555-555-5555</span>
</div>
```

```css
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}

html {
    width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#CCC;
  text-align: center;
    }

#ribbon {
    padding: .5em 2em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position:relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 20px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #5f85b4;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#ribbon:before, #ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    width:1em;
    top:-.5em;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border: .9em solid #1eb2df;
    z-index:-2;
    }

#ribbon:before {
    left:-1.5em;
    }

#ribbon:after {
    right:-1.5em;
    }

#content:before, #content:after {
    content:"";
    bottom:2.1em;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #2c4059 transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index:-1;
    }

#content:before {
      left: 0;
      border-width: .5em 1em 0 0;
    }

#content:after {
      right: 0;
      border-width: .5em 0 0 1em;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` and some markup changes to achieve the results you are going for.

I removed your `#content` as it's a redundant identifier.  You can use ancestor selections from the `#ribbon` to achieve the same results, without hogging a unique ID.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ribbon">
    <div>
        <span>Call us today! 555-555-5555</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ribbon {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position:relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 20px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
}

#ribbon:before, #ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    width:25%;
    top:-.5em;
    position:absolute;
    display: table-cell;
    border: .9em solid #1eb2df;
    z-index:-2;
    }

#ribbon:before {
    left:-1.5em;
}

#ribbon:after {
    right:-1.5em;
}

#ribbon > div {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width: 53%;
}

#ribbon span {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 20px 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #5f85b4;
    padding: .5em 2em;
    position: relative;
}

#ribbon span:before, #ribbon span:after {
    content:"";
    bottom:2.1em;
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #2c4059 transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index:-1;
    top: -10px;
}

#ribbon span:before {
    left: 0;
    border-width: .5em 1em 0 0;
}

#ribbon span:after {
    right: 0;
    border-width: .5em 0 0 1em;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vPJ8g/4/

Comment: Awesome! Do you know how I can flip those dark blue "fold" areas?

Answer (score 0):

To get the ribbon to stretch across the whole page, make `#ribbon:before` and `#ribbon:after` really big and use a combination of positioning and margins to get them where they need to be:

```
#ribbon:before {
    width: 1000000em;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -1000000.8em;
}
#ribbon:after {
    width: 1000000em;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -1000000.8em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/vPJ8g/7/

And to flip the triangular folds bits just play with the `border-color` property:

```
#content:before {
    left: 0;
    border-width: .5em 1em 0 0;
    border-color: transparent #2c4059 transparent transparent;
}
#content:after {
    right: 0;
    border-width: .5em 0 0 1em;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2c4059;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/vPJ8g/8/